# How to capture video using custom camera

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avcapturesession

I have set up my custom camera, and already coded the video preview. I have  a button on the screen that i want to use to capture video when it is pressed. I don't know how to go about it. Everything so far is set up and working fine.

In the start recording button function, i just need the code necessary to capture the video and save it. Thank you

```
class CameraViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {

@IBOutlet var recordOutlet: UIButton!


@IBOutlet var recordLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var cameraView: UIView!
var tempImage: UIImageView?

var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
var stillImageOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var currentCaptureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?

var usingFrontCamera = false

/* This is the function i want to use to start
recording a video */

@IBAction func recordingButton(_ sender: Any) {



}
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems as though Apple prefers developers to use the default camera for capturing video. If you are ok with that, I found a tutorial online with code to help.  https://www.raywenderlich.com/94404/play-record-merge-videos-ios-swift.

You can scroll down to the "recording video" section and it will walk you through it with code.

Here's some of what it says: "

```
import MobileCoreServices
```

You’ll also need to adopt the same protocols as PlayVideoViewController, by adding the following to the end of the file:

```
`extension RecordVideoViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
```

`}`

`extension RecordVideoViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
}`

Add the following code to RecordVideoViewController:

```
`func startCameraFromViewController(viewController: UIViewController, withDelegate delegate: protocol<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>) -> Bool {
  if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera) == false {
    return false
  }

  var cameraController = UIImagePickerController()
  cameraController.sourceType = .Camera
  cameraController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as NSString as String]
  cameraController.allowsEditing = false
  cameraController.delegate = delegate

  presentViewController(cameraController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  return true
}`
```

This method follows the same logic is in PlayVideoViewController, but it accesses the .Camera instead to record video.
Now add the following to record(_:):

```
startCameraFromViewController(self, withDelegate: self)
```

You are again in familiar territory. The code simply calls `startCameraControllerFromViewController(_:usingDelegate:)` when you tap the “Record Video” button.

Build and run to see what you’ve got so far.
Go to the Record screen and press the “Record Video” button. Instead of the Photo Gallery, the camera UI opens. Start recording a video by tapping the red record button at the bottom of the screen, and tap it again when you’re done recording."

Cheers,
Theo

Answer (score 1):

Here is worked code, you need to deal correct with `optional` values and `error` handling in real project, but you can use this next code as example:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  CustomCamera
//
//  Created by Taras Chernyshenko on 6/27/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Taras Chernyshenko. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AssetsLibrary

class CameraViewController: UIViewController,
    AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate,
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var recordOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var recordLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var cameraView: UIView!
    var tempImage: UIImageView?

    private var session: AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    private var deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
    private var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    private var videoOutput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    private var audioOutput: AVCaptureAudioDataOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()

    private var videoDevice: AVCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
    private var audioConnection: AVCaptureConnection?
    private var videoConnection: AVCaptureConnection?

    private var assetWriter: AVAssetWriter?
    private var audioInput: AVAssetWriterInput?
    private var videoInput: AVAssetWriterInput?

    private var fileManager: FileManager = FileManager()
    private var recordingURL: URL?

    private var isCameraRecording: Bool = false
    private var isRecordingSessionStarted: Bool = false

    private var recordingQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "recording.queue")
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
    var stillImageOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var currentCaptureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?

    var usingFrontCamera = false

    /* This is the function i want to use to start
     recording a video */

    @IBAction func recordingButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if self.isCameraRecording {
            self.stopRecording()
        } else {
            self.startRecording()
        }
        self.isCameraRecording = !self.isCameraRecording
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        self.session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

        self.recordingURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(NSTemporaryDirectory() as String)/file.mov")
        if self.fileManager.isDeletableFile(atPath: self.recordingURL!.path) {
            _ = try? self.fileManager.removeItem(atPath: self.recordingURL!.path)
        }

        self.assetWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(outputURL: self.recordingURL!,
            fileType: AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie)

        let audioSettings = [
            AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatAppleIMA4,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 1,
            AVSampleRateKey : 16000.0
        ] as [String : Any]

        let videoSettings = [
            AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecH264,
            AVVideoWidthKey : UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,
            AVVideoHeightKey : UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
        ] as [String : Any]

        self.videoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo,
             outputSettings: videoSettings)
        self.audioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio,
             outputSettings: audioSettings)

        self.videoInput?.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
        self.audioInput?.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true

        if self.assetWriter!.canAdd(self.videoInput!) {
            self.assetWriter?.add(self.videoInput!)
        }

        if self.assetWriter!.canAdd(self.audioInput!) {
            self.assetWriter?.add(self.audioInput!)
        }

        self.deviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: self.videoDevice)

        if self.session.canAddInput(self.deviceInput) {
            self.session.addInput(self.deviceInput)
        }

        self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session)
        self.previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect

        let rootLayer = self.view.layer
        rootLayer.masksToBounds = true
        self.previewLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

        rootLayer.insertSublayer(self.previewLayer!, at: 0)

        self.session.startRunning()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.session.beginConfiguration()

            if self.session.canAddOutput(self.videoOutput) {
                self.session.addOutput(self.videoOutput)
            }

            self.videoConnection = self.videoOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
            if self.videoConnection?.isVideoStabilizationSupported == true {
                self.videoConnection?.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = .auto
            }
            self.session.commitConfiguration()

            let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)
            let audioIn = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice)

            if self.session.canAddInput(audioIn) {
                self.session.addInput(audioIn)
            }

            if self.session.canAddOutput(self.audioOutput) {
                self.session.addOutput(self.audioOutput)
            }

            self.audioConnection = self.audioOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)
        }
    }

    private func startRecording() {
        if self.assetWriter?.startWriting() != true {
            print("error: \(self.assetWriter?.error.debugDescription ?? "")")
        }

        self.videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: self.recordingQueue)
        self.audioOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: self.recordingQueue)
    }

    private func stopRecording() {
        self.videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(nil, queue: nil)
        self.audioOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(nil, queue: nil)

        self.assetWriter?.finishWriting {
            print("saved")
        }
    }
    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer
        sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        if !self.isRecordingSessionStarted {
            let presentationTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
            self.assetWriter?.startSession(atSourceTime: presentationTime)
            self.isRecordingSessionStarted = true
        }

        let description = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer)!

        if CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaType(description) == kCMMediaType_Audio {
            if self.audioInput!.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                print("appendSampleBuffer audio");
                self.audioInput?.append(sampleBuffer)
            }
        } else {
            if self.videoInput!.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                print("appendSampleBuffer video");
                if !self.videoInput!.append(sampleBuffer) {
                    print("Error writing video buffer");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the video without sound 
can you please help